# Exit scripts for a VirtualBox X-session with Windows 8 guest OS

Tags: scripts, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial.

The thing is, I've been trying to create an X-session which directly boots into Windows 8 of VirtualBox which I achieved by following the instructions [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/log-into-a-virtualbox-session-in-ubuntu/).

But the problem is, when I shutdown from guest OS it returns back to login screen. Instead I want to shutdown my PC. So, is there a way to create a script that runs automatically when closing VirtualBox session?

**Edit:** One more thing.. There should be an action (a shortcut) that brings back the login manager, so that I can switch back to Ubuntu session. Otherwise I can't exit VirtualBox session, since I have enabled automatic login.

Comment: @AndroidDev The first option brings another problem ( also I've replaced 'gnome-session-quit --poweroff' with 'systemctl poweroff' ). I've edited the question. The second answer.... that I cannot understand. Also I've edited the title so that it fits correctly.

Comment: @AndroidDev Also, with what I've understood from the code in first answer, the script just keeps running in the background until session is closed. Is there a more effective way to do it? Like an event handler?